# Second password for a given set up pages in Rails - Not MFA

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

In my Rails app, we use Devise gem for authentication and authorization.  But for viewing some of the pages clients want a second password to be entered who will act like super users.  This is not an Multi-Factor authentication request, but a kind of One Time Password (OTP) for a given set of pages/resources, just that the OTP will be static.

Devise does not provide this feature. Googling hasn't helped.  Any idea how could this be achieved?

Comment: Creating another field with secure password might be a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a bit of an anti-pattern. Why not have an additional field on `User` that denotes if the user is a super user or not?

This has the benefits that:

- there is no password to remember and distribute
- super users have one less step to perform
- you can easily remove users from this group, if needed
- you don't need to build a secondary login form/page